# Windows Server 2008 SP2 on an Exchange 2007/DC server?

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-server-2008

I want to apply SP2 for Windows Server 2008 on our production Exchange 2007 / Domain Controller server which is currently running on Windows Server 2008 RTM. For the moment, lets skip the lecture on having the DC and the Exchange Server on the same box. I just recently started at this job and this setup was decided on by my predecessor. Suffice it to say that I plan to change this as soon as budget, etc. allow.

Has anyone had any problems applying SP2 for Windows Server 2008 on an Exchange Server? I have deployed it to the only other 2008 box we're running currently, although its just a straightforward file server.

The Exchange config is straightforward, a single server serving all our users.

One more thing, this server is situated at a hosting facility in Johannesburg, I am in Cape Town, so remote access is all I have, although the hosting company could physically access the box if needed.

Comment: I take it you mean you want to install SP2 for Server 2008, rather upgrading a 2003 server to 2008 SP2?

Comment: @Tubs: correct. I've edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have SP2 for 2008 installed on our exchange server with no problems. Our system does not have a bundled DC though, so there may be some consideration there that I am not aware of.

I would also suggest making sure you have the latest Cumulative update from MS. I believe one of them added support for SP2, but I can't recall.

Comment: I made sure there were no other outstanding updates and everything looked healthy in the event logs before starting the SP2 installation. Didn't have any issues during or afterwards. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just as a tip, after installation of SP2 for WS2008 a good addition would be SP2 for Exchange, just to get things update and avoid any possible future problems. BTW what SP your Exchange have?